# Advanced search between two dates in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I use this code for advance search

```
public ActionResult AdvanceSearch(string HeadTitle, string fulltext, string firstdate, string enddate, string newstype)
    {
        var q = db.Tbl_News.Where(n => n.HeadTitle.Contains(HeadTitle) && n.FullText.Contains(fulltext) && n.Date >= firstdate && n.Date <= enddate);
        return PartialView("AdvanceSearch", q);
    }
```

this code work for Search in HeadTitle and full text but when I add date show me an error .

How use this code for search between two dates ?

Comment: Start by making your parameters `DateTime` (not `string`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks . its work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your date parameters should be of type `DateTime`,
and I suggest updating your code to be like

```
var q = db.Tbl_News
            .Where (n => n.HeadTitle.Contains(HeadTitle) 
            .Where (n => n.FullText.Contains(fulltext)) 
            .Where (n => n.Date >= firstdate.Date )
            .Where (n => n.Date <= enddate.Date);
```

to be more readable, and compare just the date part (ignore time)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the **parameter type,** this is also fine.

```
public ActionResult AdvanceSearch(string HeadTitle, string fulltext, string firstdate, string enddate, string newstype)
{
    var q = db.Tbl_News
        .Where (n => n.HeadTitle.Contains(HeadTitle) 
        .Where (n => n.FullText.Contains(fulltext)) 
        .Where (n => n.Date >= DateTime.ParseExact(firstdate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        .Where (n => n.Date <= DateTime.ParseExact(enddate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```